# Can you use a weebly website for your apps feedback website?

Tags: ios

Question pretty much is it. Can I use a website made with weebly as my feedback website? When submitting my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen anything in the Developer Guidelines that talks about the use or non-use of any particular web platform for your web presence. Having said that, only Apple is able to give you a definite answer regarding it's guidelines, and you are bound to merely get opinions here, like mine.